# After set true Material3, Widget become zoom while refresh use Smartrefresher

Tags: flutter

The child widget of Smartrefresher become zoom in, while refresh, this behaviour found after set Material3 to true.

example bug zoom

[image]

below the code

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('SmartRefresher Auto Zoom'),
      ),
      body: SmartRefresher(
        onRefresh: () async {
          // refreshController.requestRefresh();
          // await Future.delayed(Durations.extralong1);
          // refreshController.refreshCompleted();
        },
        controller: refreshController,
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverList.builder(
              itemBuilder: (_, i) => Text('data $i'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

how to remove this behaviour on material3?

Comment: The pull_to_refresh package has not been updated for 2 years, have you considered using Flutter's [RefreshIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html) instead?

Comment: yes I'm considering it, previously I saw there was an update to the pull_to_refresh_flutter3 package (smartrefresher) in pubdev, it said 2 months ago.